# How to reform a relative clause into a one-level sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clause, participle

I’m having difficulties transforming such relative clauses into a one-level sentence. Is my way below right?

> Ein Sonett, das aus vierzehn Zeilen besteht, ist eine lyrische Gedichtform. → Ein Sonett ist eine aus vierzehn Zeilen bestehende lyrische Gedichtform.

Comment: It’s OK in general (note that I made some minor corrections in an edit), but you effectively moved the part: In the first sentence, it’s the sonnet that has 14 lines; in the second, it’s the poetic form that has 14 lines. So they are not actually equivalent. Be also warned that, even when the transformation is correctly done, there may be a big _stylistic_ difference between the version with the relative clause and the one with a participle.

Comment: Yes it's OK and generally my last edit is valid. Because i always forget what i have said,eaten,written. Actually i don't remember older shape of my question so sorry :-(

Comment: Huh? No need to remember anything, just look into the revision history.

Comment: i'll find revision history, i didn't know i had that option thanks

Comment: i couldn't find revision history do mean my browser settings or is there such section here?

Comment: Click on the text “Edited 1 hour ago”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31294/discussion-between-user1474062-and-chirlu).

Comment: Just to add to that: revision history is not available in the (Android) app...

Answer (score 2):

General strategy: Identify the noun that the relative clause refers to (in most cases the one directly in front), transform the verb of the relative clause into a participle, and put the resulting participle clause in front of the noun. It works in a similar way in English.

> Ein **Sonett**, **das** aus vierzehn Zeilen **besteht**, ist eine lyrische Gedichtform ->
> Ein *aus vierzehn Zeilen **bestehendes** Sonett* ist eine lyrische Gedichtform.
>
> Ein Sonett ist eine **Gedichtform**, **die** aus vierzehn Zeilen **besteht** -> Ein Sonett ist eine *aus vierzehn Zeilen **bestehende** Gedichtform*.

(Of course the second variant makes more sense.)

In English:

> A **sonnet**, that/which **consists** of fourteen lines, is a poetic form -> A *sonnet **consisting** of fourteen lines* is a poetical form.
>
> A sonnet is a **poetic form** that **consists** of fourteen lines -> A sonnet is a *poetic form **consisting** of fourteen lines.*

Comment: as a relative clause "das üblicherwise in  gereimten jambischen Fünfheber geschrieben ist" do i need to use _in_ or _mit_ and _ein Lyrik schreiben_ or _ein Lyrik verfassen_ ?

Comment: That's two new questions. :-) The expressions are "etwas *in* einer Reimform schreiben" (but "etwas *mit* einem Schreibinstrument schreiben"), so it's "in". You can't use "Lyrik" as a translation of "(song) lyrics", so you probably mean "einen Gedichttext/einen Liedtext schreiben/verfassen" (all combinations are correct, "verfassen" is more elevated style).